# Extracting Data from non-JSON API url

Tags: javascript, json, api

I would to set expectations first. I know basic HTML, and understand CSS, vbScript and JavaScript but not an expert, not even intermediate.

I want to extract data from an API url that looks like [this](http://api.domain.com/?type=domain_rank&key=somekey&export_columns=Dn,Rk,Or,Ot,Oc,Ad,At,Ac&domain=somedomain..com&database=us)...

and the browser returns these data...

```
Domain;Rank;Organic Keywords;Organic Traffic;Organic Cost;Adwords Keywords;Adwords Traffic;Adwords Cost

somedomain.com;31970;26015;35679;252734;0;0;0
```

How can I get these data into a JSON file so I can create a JavaScript for it.

Thanks!

Comment: you need to write a parser for it if they don't have a query param you can set for format json

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that's the exact format returned? It could actually be XML but because you're looking at it in your browser, you don't see the tags. I suggest you try `curl` or at least, view the page source in your browser

Comment: i looked in page source and i'm not sure if it's xml or script

Answer (score 0):

You can split the String, then assign the parts to an object manually:

```js
var response = "Domain;Rank;Organic Keywords;Organic Traffic;Organic Cost;Adwords Keywords;Adwords Traffic;Adwords Cost;somedomain.com;31970;26015;35679;252734;0;0;0";

var fields = ["Dn", "Rk", "Or", "Ot", "Oc", "Ad", "At", "Ac", null, "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4"];

var data = response.split(";");
var parsedData = {};

fields.forEach(function(fld, i) {
  if (fld) parsedData[fld] = data[i];
});

console.log(parsedData);
```

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but how do i get the data first into my script?

something like src="url"???

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yavrYj?editors=1111

split by the semicolon, break them up into two arrays (key, value) then make the json object

```
 var data = "Domain; Rank; Organic Keywords; Organic Traffic;Organic Cost;Adwords Keywords;Adwords Traffic; Adwords Cost; somedomain.com;31970;26015;35679;252734;0;0;0"
var values = data.split(";")
var half = values.length / 2
var keys = values.splice(0,half);
var jsonData = {};
for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) { 
  jsonData[keys[i]] = values[i]
}
```

the result is

```
Object {
   Adwords Cost: "0",
   Organic Keywords: "26015",
   Organic Traffic: "35679",
   Rank: "31970",
  Adwords Keywords: "0",
  Adwords Traffic: "0",
  Domain: " somedomain.com",
  Organic Cost: "252734"
}
```

you had asked in your comment how do you get your data from the api?

If you are using jquery ajax I guess it would be something like

```
$(function() {

  $.ajax("http://api.domain.com/?type=domain_rank&key=somekey&export_columns=Dn,Rk,Or,Ot,Oc,Ad,At,Ac&domain=somedomain..com&database=us",
{
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'text',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        var values = data.split(";")
var half = values.length / 2
var keys = values.splice(0,half);
var jsonData = {};
for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) { 
  jsonData[keys[i]] = values[i]
}

    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(xhr.responseText); 
    }
});
});
```

however if you are attempting to call this api from javascript on a different domain you may run into CORS problems.

Comment: you could also probably use underscoreJS and its object function http://underscorejs.org/#object

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but how do i get the data first into my script?

something like src="url"???